# Detect tap event on any component?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Please let me know the code. I tried from the Ajax Listener which is defined in the app.js.But I want to detect user's tap in my application by just writing some tap listener in app.js. Any idea what tap listener should I write? The AJAX listener is:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete',function(connection,options) {
                   Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                  anyfunction();
               });
```

Comment: Why you need to use ajax to detect tap event?

Comment: Sorry no AJax calls. Actually what I want that if a user tap any component in sencha touch 2 I should know. By writing a code only in app.js or bootstrap.

Comment: You can always listen to the click event on the window object.